# how to convert an array of characters in c to a string so as to do string operations on it?

Tags: c

suppose there is a string of characters in an array of d[20] . How to convert to a string d so that i can use it in string functions like strcmp..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be null-terminated. That's the only requirement. I presume you know how to do that.

Comment: yup .. i do know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Null terminate the string.  That is, set the character after the last character in your string to zero.

Answer (score 1):

it's already something on which you can operate with standard string functions, assuming that it ends with `'\0'` since it's a requirement: it needs to know when the string ends.

You can prepare the space of `char[]` by memsetting it with `memset(string, 0, length)`.